# Trapping ctrl+n key combination in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to trap <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> key in chrome (by using javascript, jquery or any plugin)? I need to assign <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> key to particular task, but as soon as I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, chrome opens a new window. I am able to trap <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> in firefox by using:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

but its not working in chrome.

Comment: *"I am able to trap ctrl+n in firefox by using event.preventDefault() but its not working in chrome."* Always best to show your code, but it's academic in this case: You can't do it, see the other question userD points to.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632062/ways-to-detect-ctrl-n-or-when-a-user-opens-a-new-window

Comment: got it...its not possible in chrome 4 as of now.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for your issue.

```
// defining flags
var isCtrl = false;
var isShift = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // action on key up
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 17) {
            isCtrl = false;
        }
        if (e.which == 16) {
            isShift = false;
        }
    });


   $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 17) {
            isCtrl = true;
        }
        if (e.which == 16) {
            isShift = true;
        }

if ((e.which == 110 || e.which == 78) && isCtrl) {
            e.preventDefault(true);
}
});
```